# Python issue adding a column to a dataframe using a function I have defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm really new to Python (knew nothing before Christmas), am self taught and am having a bit of an issue with dataframes.

I'm importing data from a CSV into a dataframe in Python using Pandas.
This data has a DateTime field called "ItemTime".
What I need to do is split ItemTime into "Date" and "TimeSlot" and add them both as columns into the dataframe so I can then summarise by Date and TimeSlot (amongst other things).
TimeSlot is the 15 minute time slot ItemTime fits in.
So if the DateTime = 2020-10-14T11:34:00.767 I need a new Date column to contain "2020-10-14", and a new TimeSlot column to contain "11:30:00 - 11:45:00".

I have created a function that generates this TimeSlot value (my_TimeSlot) with two inputs - hour and minute.

I have managed to get the Date column working but am having issues with the TimeSlot.
I've also added fields to the dataframe for the Hour and Minute that I require for my function as I couldn't get it to work in one go but I'm still not having any joy.

This is what I have that is giving me the Date, Hour and Minute fields:

```
detail = pd.read_csv(<the filename>, usecols=['SiteID', 'TransactionID', 'ItemTime', 'TotalGross', 'TotalNet' ])

fnDate = lambda row: datetime.datetime.date(datetime.datetime.strptime(row.ItemTime[0:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))

detail['Date'] = detail.apply(fnDate, axis=1)

fnHour = lambda row: datetime.datetime.strptime(row.ItemTime[0:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').hour

detail['Hour'] = detail.apply(fnHour, axis=1)

fnMinute = lambda row: datetime.datetime.strptime(row.ItemTime[0:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').minute

detail['Minute'] = detail.apply(fnMinute, axis=1)
```

This is my TimeSlot function which also works when run independently

```
def my_TimeSlot(fhour,fminute):
if fminute >= 45:
    smin = '45'
    emin = '00'
elif fminute >= 30 :
    smin = '30'
    emin = '45'
elif fminute >= 15 :
    smin = '15'
    emin = '30'
else :
    smin = '00'
    emin = '15'
    
shour = str(fhour)
if emin == '00' :
    ehour = str(fhour+1)
else :
    ehour = str(fhour)
    
starttimeslot = shour+':'+smin+':00'
endtimeslot = ehour+':'+emin+':00'

return (starttimeslot+' - '+endtimeslot)
```

The problem comes in when I try to use this function in the process of adding a column to the dataframe.

I have tried both of these commands below but it comes back with the same error - "NameError: name 'my_TimeSlot' is not defined".

1

```
detail['TimeSlot'] = detail.apply(my_TimeSlot(Hour, Minute), axis=1)
```

2

```
fnTS = lambda row: my_TimeSlot(row.Hour, row.Minute)
detail['TimeSlot'] = detail.apply(fnTS, axis=1)
```

I even tried doing it without needing to create the additional Hour and Minute columns

```
detail['TimeSlot'] = my_TimeSlot(datetime.datetime.strptime(detail.ItemTime[0:19],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').hour,
    datetime.datetime.strptime(detail.ItemTime[0:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').minute)
```

...but I still get the same error message.

The defined function my_TimeSlot is saved in the same .py file as the main program so I'm a bit lost as to why it doesn't recognise it. I've tried positioning it at the top and at the bottom of the file but it makes no difference.

I have searched the web but nothing I have found describes this problem with a user-defined function, only "simple" functions like adding two numbers together.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is doing my head in.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked with pandas, that being said it doesn't look like you turned details into a data frame so you won't have all the functionality of a data frame.

Have you tried

`detail = pd.read_csv(<the filename>, usecols=['SiteID', 'TransactionID', 'ItemTime', 'TotalGross', 'TotalNet' ]).DataFrame()`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reading my post. I just tried adding that and it now comes back with "AttributeError:'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'" which, as I read it, suggests that the original object was a dataframe after all.  I'll have a read through the link you shared. Thanks.

Comment: I added a type check "print(type(detail))" below the detail = ... line and it prints "<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>". I assume that means it is a dataframe, but I don't know if there are different types of dataframe or just the one returned.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

There's probably a more efficient way to do what you want though - for example extract the time, round it down to the nearest 15 minute interval and go from there.

```python
detail['TimeSlot'] = detail.apply(lambda row: my_TimeSlot(row['Hour'], row['Minute']), axis=1)
```

### Full Code

```python
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

def my_TimeSlot(fhour,fminute):
    if fminute >= 45:
        smin = '45'
        emin = '00'
    elif fminute >= 30:
        smin = '30'
        emin = '45'
    elif fminute >= 15:
        smin = '15'
        emin = '30'
    else :
        smin = '00'
        emin = '15'
        
    shour = str(fhour)
    if emin == '00' :
        ehour = str(fhour+1)
    else :
        ehour = str(fhour)
        
    starttimeslot = shour+':'+smin+':00'
    endtimeslot = ehour+':'+emin+':00'

    return (starttimeslot+' - '+endtimeslot)

detail = pd.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=['SiteID', 'TransactionID', 'ItemTime', 'TotalGross', 'TotalNet' ])

fnDate = lambda row: datetime.date(datetime.strptime(row.ItemTime[0:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))

detail['Date'] = detail.apply(fnDate, axis=1)

fnHour = lambda row: datetime.strptime(row.ItemTime[0:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').hour

detail['Hour'] = detail.apply(fnHour, axis=1)

fnMinute = lambda row: datetime.strptime(row.ItemTime[0:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').minute

detail['Minute'] = detail.apply(fnMinute, axis=1)

detail['TimeSlot'] = detail.apply(lambda row: my_TimeSlot(row['Hour'], row['Minute']), axis=1)

print(detail)
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed "row.Hour" and "row.Minute" to "row['Hour']" and row['Minute'] from your code and it works perfectly. Next step, summarisation.